# Поиск подохдящей библиотеки для транскрибации и озвучки текста

Tags: c#, .net, .net-core, raspberry-pi

Я пишу своего голосвого ассистента, использую .net core 7-х версии. Решение пишу на линуксе, планирую потом затолкать это все на raspberry. Необходимо подобрать либу/ы для того чтобы можно было озвучивать какой-то определенный текст, а так же чтобы 24/7 выполнялась прослушка с помощью микрофона до тех пор пока не прозвучит какое-то кодовое приветствие (нечто в духе "привет сири"), и затем выполнялась транскрибация команды. Просьба к ответу приложить так же какие-то ссылки на подходящие примеры

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Для реализации голосового ассистента на .NET Core, можно попробовать эти библиотеки:

**System.Speech**: это стандартная библиотека .NET Framework, которая позволяет синтезировать речь и распознавать речь с помощью встроенных механизмов. Однако, поскольку .NET Core не поддерживает эту библиотеку, вы можете использовать стороннюю библиотеку, такую как SpeechLib, которая предоставляет аналогичные возможности.

**NAudio**: это библиотека .NET, которая предоставляет доступ к аудио-устройствам и позволяет записывать и воспроизводить звук. Она может быть использована для записи аудио с микрофона и воспроизведения звука с помощью голосового синтеза.

**PocketSphinx**: это открытая библиотека для распознавания речи, которая может быть использована для обработки речи, записанной с микрофона. Она может быть использована для распознавания команд, произнесенных пользователем.

Что касается примеров, вот некоторые ссылки на полезные материалы:

Пример голосового синтеза с использованием **NAudio**: https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/98355/NAudio-Wave-Tutorials-Part-5-Synthesizing-Speech

Пример распознавания речи с **PocketSphinx**:
https://cmusphinx.github.io/wiki/tutorialpocketsphinx/

Пример использования голосовых команд с помощью **PocketSphinx**: https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/602829/Speech-recognition-with-PocketSphinx